# Expected 'language', 'defined_in', or 'generated_declaration' while archiving the build

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, ios7, clang++

I have objective c project which have Swift ACTabScrollView library in it.
project is working fine on simulator and device.But when i try to archive the build 
Xcode generate some code automatically and shows the following error

**Expected 'language', 'defined_in', or 'generated_declaration'**

```
   # pragma clang attribute 
   push(__attribute__((external_source_symbol(language="Swift", 
   defined_in="Sallati",generated_declaration))), 
   apply_to=any(function,enum,objc_interface,objc_category,objc_protocol))
   # pragma pop_macro("any")
   #endif
```

**#pragma clang attribute pop' with no matching '#pragma clang attribute push'**

```
#if __has_attribute(external_source_symbol)
# pragma clang attribute pop
#endif
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[Please see the image for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxs3W.jpg)